# Screecapture maintaining underlying resolution

Tags: screenshot

My daughter (11y) is taking screenshots (rectangular areas) of photos in websites with Faststone Capture for some schoolwork.

It seems the underlying resolution of the photos are lost.

Is there some way to take such a shoot without losing underlying resolution/avoid generation loss.

(Can be a browser specific tool).

This is typically a part of a photo in the page.

With losing underlying resolution I mean that capture seems to be with the resolution of the browser.  Not the full resolution of the image included in the page.

Comment: Can't she just right click and save photo on the website (unless they disable it).

Comment: He didn't said she is only capturing images, so right click isn't solution.

Comment: "screenshot of photos" but either way the question should be clearer.

Comment: @shinjijai : It is typically a part of a photo.  (I think going through a photo editor is a bit to complex)

Answer (score 0):

If she is using Windows 7, there is integrated tool called "Snipping tool",
and for Windows XP she can download XP version "Windows XP Snipping Tool", for Mac there is "Grab" tool. Chrome has a browser tool named "Awesome Screenshot" link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce.

Comment: I will have a closer look, but I don't see anything about underlying resolution.